No funciona el servidor de laravel en UniServer Zero XV
He presentado algunos inconvenientes para instalar Laravel 11.14.0 en UniServer Zero XV para Windows con PHP 8.3.8 que he ido solucionando agregando ciertas líneas al archivo php_cli, pero con este no he podio, me funciona bien los comandos, puedo crear migraciones, etc. Pero al ejecutar php artisan serve me carga una página de laravel con este error:
could not find driver (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = yuAHVIlnaYeGRCOy90UR6i1iuYfR2bDt7s3ekuBQ limit 1)

He verificado que la base de datos seleccionada sea mysqli y que estén bien los datos en el archivo .env, he ejecutado el servidor mysql pero sigue dando ese error.
Algo que me aparece al correr php artisan serve es lo siguiente:
php artisan serve
  <br />
  <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\mysqli (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_mysqli.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
  <br />
  <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'fileinfo' (tried: 
/core/php83/extensions\fileinfo (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_fileinfo.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
  <br />
  <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\gd (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_gd.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
  <br />
  <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: 
/core/php83/extensions\mbstring (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_mbstring.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
  <br />
  <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'exif' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\exif (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_exif.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in <b>n 
known</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
  <br />
  <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\mysqli (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_mysqli.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
  <br />
  <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\openssl (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_openssl.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
  <br />
  <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mysqli.dll' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\php_mysqli.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_php_mysqli.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el 
módulo especificado)) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
  <br />
  <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_mysql.dll' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\php_pdo_mysql.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_php_pdo_mysql.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
  <br />
  <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_fileinfo.dll' 
(tried: /core/php83/extensions\php_fileinfo.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_php_fileinfo.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
  <br />
  <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_gd.dll' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\php_gd.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_php_gd.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
  <br />
  <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mbstring.dll' 
(tried: /core/php83/extensions\php_mbstring.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_php_mbstring.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
  <br />
  <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_exif.dll' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\php_exif.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_php_exif.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
  <br />
  <b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_openssl.dll' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\php_openssl.dll (No se puede encontrar [Wed Jul  3 23:37:31 2024] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\mysqli (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_mysqli.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'fileinfo' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\fileinfo (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_fileinfo.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\gd (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_gd.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\mbstring (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_mbstring.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'exif' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\exif (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_exif.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknow  
on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\mysqli (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_mysqli.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\openssl (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_openssl.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mysqli.dll' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\php_mysqli.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_php_mysqli.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_mysql.dll' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\php_pdo_mysql.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_php_pdo_mysql.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_fileinfo.dll' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\php_fileinfo.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_php_fileinfo.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar 
el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_gd.dll' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\php_gd.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_php_gd.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mbstring.dll' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\php_mbstring.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_php_mbstring.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar 
el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_exif.dll' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\php_exif.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_php_exif.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_openssl.dll' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\php_openssl.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_php_openssl.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el 
módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sockets.dll' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\php_sockets.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_php_sockets.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el 
módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_zip.dll' (tried: 
/core/php83/extensions\php_zip.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_php_zip.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_com_dotnet.dll' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\php_com_dotnet.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo 
especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_php_com_dotnet.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sockets' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\sockets (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_sockets.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zip' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\zip (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_zip.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on 
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'com_dotnet' (tried: /core/php83/extensions\com_dotnet (No se puede encontrar el 
módulo especificado), /core/php83/extensions\php_com_dotnet.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0

   INFO  Server running on [http://127.0.0.1:8000].

Alguien le ha sucedido esto o sabe por qué pasa? He investigando e intentado varias cosas y no doy con la solución, cualquier ayuda o pista es bienvenida.
Edit: Incluyo captura de los archivos


Los mensajes dicen claramente que no se logran cargar las bibliotecas dinámicas (dll's). Revisa las rutas que están configuradas y que estén presentes los archivos en dichas rutas.

@jachguate los dll están en su carpeta y están activados, lo que no sé dónde revisar las rutas

Están en el archivo de configuración de php, usualmente llamado php.ini

La ruta para cargar extensiones parece estar bien, no sé qué pasa, lo q hice fue instalar composer desde una versión de php de wamp y funciona bien, no sé qué pasa con Uniserver

El mensaje de error tiene las rutas que está probando. ¿son las correctas? ¿Los archivos están allí?

En teoría creo que sí, puse una captura de mi carpeta de extensiones donde se ve la ruta

En cambio yo veo claramente que no. El error dice que está buscando /core/php83/extensions\php_mysqli.dll mientras que existe c:\bla\bla\core\php83/extensions\php_mysqli.dll.  Por otro lado, veo cosas peores, com oque busca /core/php83/extensions\php_php_mysqli.dll.dll (con doble extensión). Me llama la atención que las rutas de búsqueda son al estilo *nix (unix, linux, OSx, etc), mientras que tú estás ejecutando en Windows.  ¿De dónde sacaste el INI con el que estás iniciando PHP?

Por otro lado, si bien la imagen ayuda a aclarar la ruta que pretendes usar, no hace falta ver todos los archivos que tiene y, en cambio, quizás la parte relevante del php.ini si venga al caso.

@jachguate el php.ini es una copia de uno de los .ini que trae Uniserver porque por defecto no trae un php.ini si no un php_development.ini, php_production.ini, etc. La parte del archivo .ini que me parece que se refiere a las rutas es esta:
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; https://php.net/extension-dir
;extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
;extension_dir = "ext"
extension_dir = "${US_ROOTF}/core/php83/extensions"

Agrego que en php-cli.ini que es el que tuve que corregir para poder instalar laravel tiene esta ruta de extensiones: extension_dir = "extensions"
